# How to set background-color on 50% of area CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to have a div, and inside this div must be a field with some color. So i want to have div for example 200px x 200px and set background-color:gray which size ll be 100px x 100px, and start at position 50px 50px.

Please look at this snippet with code:

```css
div{
    background-color: gray;
    background-size: 100px 100px;
    background-position: 50px 50px;
    
    min-width:200px!important;
    min-height:200px!important;
    max-width:200px!important;
    max-height:200px!important; 
      
    padding:50px;
}
```

```html
<div>some text</div>
```

So as You see the background color filled all div width and height.
Is this possible to make background to fill only 50%?
[image]

Note: The red area should be transparent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can achieve this effect with a [linear gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient), [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) and [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position)

- The background looks like this:

  ```
  background:  linear-gradient(to bottom, grey 0%, grey 100%) no-repeat;
  ```

  All this linear-gradient does is give us a background colour that can be manipulated like a background image.
- The gradient is treated like an image and can be centered and re-sized:

  ```
  background-size: calc(100% - 100px) calc(100% - 100px);
  background-position: center;
  ```

The [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc) reduces the size of the background by exactly 100px and the transparent space around the div when centered is 50px in width.

#### Full example

The second div shows the true size of the div and the `20vw` width and height shows how the div can be re-sized.

```css
div {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, grey 0, grey 100%) no-repeat;
  background-size: calc(100% - 100px) calc(100% - 100px); /* Reduce height of background by 100px and width by 100px*/  
  background-position: center;
  padding: 80px;  /* 50px border + 30px additional padding */
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
}
div.no-gradient {
  background: grey;
}
/*For example*/

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, black 0%, white 100%);
}
div {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>some text</div>
<div class="no-gradient">I am the same size as the other div</div>
```

Comment: Updated in 2019 as browsers now demand `calc(100% - 100px)` twice in the `background-size`, one for the x and y axis.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have provided good workarounds. Here is the cold hard truth:

### You can’t set a background color for half an element’s content area

A background color applies to an elements content area. You can’t apply a background color to half of an element’s content area.

[Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model) explains this:

> The content area is the area containing the real content of the element. It often has a background, a color or an image (in that order, an opaque image hiding the background color) and is located inside the content edge; its dimensions are the content width, or content-box width, and the content height, or content-box height.

The content area of an element has exactly one background color. The color may be transparent, and may be inherited rather than defined, or entirely covered - but still, there is always one, and there can be only one.

Inspected elements in a browser developer's tools will help you get familiar with this.

There are many workarounds for the effect you are asking to create, including nested elements, pseudo elements, and thick borders.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve that with a `border` that has the desired thickness:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XjpbNJ

```
<div class="x">text</<div>

.x {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: grey;
  border: 100px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: i dont want to have any color in the red area, i want that red area will be transparent, and only background-color will be on center

Comment: Then use a margin instead of the border: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QKdbVR

Comment: Yea, i know this solution, but i want to use some background properties, if no one will answer this in the way i want I will mark Your answer as an accept answer. Thanks for help

Comment: third solution: a div inside a div

Answer (score 1):

Here you go..

```css
div.container {    
  width:200px;
  background:transparent;
  border: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
  padding:50px 0;
}
div.inner-container{
  background-color:gray;
  width: 100px;
  padding:25px 0;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner-container">
   ---some text---
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) and [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) can only be used for images, so you can't use them with just colors.

I would wrap that div in another and do this:

```
div.wrapper {    
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  padding:50px;
  background:red;
}
div.inner{
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0nnmr6vr/1/)

If that's not an option you could also use an image instead, and position that.

Answer (score 0):

Use a psuedoelement to simulate the coloring in the desired quadrant.